# Convert string datetime to Ruby datetime

Tags: ruby, date, datetime

How do I convert this "2013-10-20 18:36:40" into a Ruby datetime?

I'm trying the following, but it's not working:

```
"2013-10-20 18:36:40".to_datetime
```

That's making it this and missing the time:

```
2013-10-20 00:00:00 UTC
```

Comment: Your code will work if you precede it with `require 'active_support/all'` (or just `require 'active_support/core_ext/string/conversions'`) if you don't want to load it all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`DateTime::strptime`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.0/libdoc/date/rdoc/DateTime.html#method-c-strptime):

```
require 'date'
DateTime.strptime("2013-10-20 18:36:40", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
#<DateTime: 2013-10-20T18:36:40+00:00 ((2456586j,67000s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following if rails is installed on your system:--

```
require 'active_support/core_ext/string/conversions'

"2013-10-20 18:36:40".to_time



1.9.2p320 :001 > require 'active_support/core_ext/string/conversions'
 => true
1.9.2p320 :003 > "2013-10-20 18:36:40".to_time
 => 2013-10-20 18:36:40 UTC
```

Comment: active_support is available in rails, not in ruby.

Answer (score 0):

There is also `DateTime#parse` method:

```
2.1.0 :001 > require 'date'
 => true 
2.1.0 :002 > DateTime.parse('2013-10-20 18:36:40')
 => #<DateTime: 2013-10-20T18:36:40+00:00 ((2456586j,67000s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
```

If your work with rails consider writing timezone-safe code:

```
Time.zone.parse("2013-10-20 18:36:40")
```

http://www.elabs.se/blog/36-working-with-time-zones-in-ruby-on-rails